# Database table data synchronization with the help of rowversion technique

Tags: sql-server, synchronization

My company has many branches like in UK, Italy Germany etc. without using sql server built-in replication I want to synchronization table data writing a store procedure and sql server jobs.

I want when any new data will be added in UK db server then my sp will add or update that data in Germany database through link server. When Germany edit that data then the same data will be updated in UK database.

Another problem is there that suppose same data is update in Germany and UK end at same time then which one will be treated mother in this case. how to handle this situation professionally.

Can we update rowversion field manually?

If possible give me a sample code against my situation as a result I can visualize it properly which may help me to compose the whole thing.

Comment: It can be done but it will be very error prone, poor performant. By the way whats stopping you from taking advantage of sql server's built-in very sophistically architectured Replication.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very difficult problem.

If you want to try and tackle it, I suggest you read up on the idea of eventual consistency.